# How to fix Property 'betterWms' does not exist on type 'typeof tileLayer'

Tags: angular, dictionary

i am using angular 13.2.0  and  leaflet 1.7.1

imports:
.
.
import * as L from 'leaflet';
.
.

Answer (score 0):

Did you instal library with `npm install leaflet@1.7.1` ?

If so, could you reproduce your issue for example on stackblitz ?

Comment: i have installed leaflet but the problem still persist